# making print_r use PHP_EOL

Tags: php, eol

My PHP_EOL is "\r\n", however, when I do `print_r` on an array each new line has a "\n" - not a "\r\n" - placed after it.

Any idea if it's possible to change this behavior?

Comment: `\r\n` is for windows and `\n` on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use second param in `print_r` (set `true`), read DOC: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

See: 
`mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )`;

Example:

```
$eol = chr(10); //Break line in like unix
$weol = chr(13) . $eol; //Break line with "carriage return" (required by some text editors)
$data = print_r(array(...), true);
$data = str_replace(eol, weol, $data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Inchpinching: Actually your wording is not correct - `\n` is the newline for windows AND unix. Windows just requires the additional `\r` (carriage return)

Answer (score 4):

If you look the source code of `print_r` you'll find:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(print_r)
{
    zval *var;
    zend_bool do_return = 0;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z|b", &var, &do_return) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (do_return) {
        php_output_start_default(TSRMLS_C);
    }

    zend_print_zval_r(var, 0 TSRMLS_CC);

    if (do_return) {
        php_output_get_contents(return_value TSRMLS_CC);
        php_output_discard(TSRMLS_C);
    } else {
        RETURN_TRUE;
    }
}
```

ultimately you can ignore the stuff arround `zend_print_zval_r(var, 0 TSRMLS_CC);` for your question.

If you follow the stacktrace, you'll find:

```
ZEND_API void zend_print_zval_r(zval *expr, int indent TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
    zend_print_zval_r_ex(zend_write, expr, indent TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

which leads to

```
ZEND_API void zend_print_zval_r_ex(zend_write_func_t write_func, zval *expr, int indent TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
    switch (Z_TYPE_P(expr)) {
        case IS_ARRAY:
            ZEND_PUTS_EX("Array\n");
            if (++Z_ARRVAL_P(expr)->nApplyCount>1) {
                ZEND_PUTS_EX(" *RECURSION*");
                Z_ARRVAL_P(expr)->nApplyCount--;
                return;
            }
            print_hash(write_func, Z_ARRVAL_P(expr), indent, 0 TSRMLS_CC);
            Z_ARRVAL_P(expr)->nApplyCount--;
            break;
```

From this point on, you could continue to find the relevant line - but since there is already a hardcoded `"Array\n"` - i'll assume the rest of the `print_r` implementation uses the same hardcoded `\n` linebreak-thing.

So, to answer your question: You cannot change it to use `\r\n`.
Use one of the provided workarounds.

Sidenode: Since `print_r` is mainly used for debugging, this will do the job as well:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($object);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I marked Guilherme Nascimento's response as the answer since it provides a workaround but I actually like your answer better. I appreciate and respect your thoroughness!

Answer (score 2):

Like pointed out elsewhere on this page, the newlines are hardcoded in the PHP source, so you have to replace them manually.

You could use your own version of `print_r` like this:

```
namespace My;

function print_r($expression, $return = false)
{
    $out = \print_r($expression, true);
    $out = \preg_replace("#(?<!\r)\n#", PHP_EOL, $out);
    if ($return) {
        return $out;
    }
    echo $out;
    return true;
}
```

Whenever you want to use it, you just import it with

```
// aliasing a function (PHP 5.6+)
use My\print_r as print_r;

print_r("A string with \r\n is not replaced");
print_r("A string with \n is replaced");
```

This will then use `PHP_EOL` for newlines. Note that it will only substitute newlines, e.g. `\n`, but not any `\r\n` you might have in the `$expression`. This is to prevent any `\r\n` to become `\r\r\n`.

The benefit of doing it this way is that it will work as a drop-in replacement of the native function. So any code that already uses the native `print_r` can be replaced simply by adding the use statement.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you could capture the `print_r()` output using buffer output, then use `str_replace()` to replace existences of `\n` with your `PHP_EOL`. In this example I've replaced it with `x` to show that it's working...

```
ob_start();

$test_array = range('A', 'Z');
print_r($test_array);

$dump = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

As pointed out by dognose, since PHP 4.3 you can return the result of `print_r()` into a string (more elegant):

```
$dump = print_r($test_array, true);
```

Then replace line endings:

```
$dump = str_replace("\n", "x" . PHP_EOL, $dump);
echo $dump;
```

Output:

```
Arrayx
(x
    [0] => Ax
    [1] => Bx
    [2] => Cx
    [3] => Dx
    [4] => Ex
    [5] => Fx
    [6] => Gx
    ... etc
    [25] => Zx
)x
```

Comment: indeed this is not elegant. You could use `$val = print_r($something, true);` since php 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Question [Is it possible to change the behavior of PHP's print_r function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693006/is-it-possible-to-change-the-behavior-of-phps-print-r-function) was marked was duplicated of this one . I'd like to answer more how is possible change the behavior of print_r. My propose is do another function with another name that do the print_r customized . And we just need replace print_r functions with print_r_pretty ...

```
function print_r_pretty($in, $saveToString = false) {
    $out = print_r($in, true);
    $out = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $out);
    switch ($saveToString) {
      case true: return $out;
      default: echo $out;
    }
  }
```

But line :

```
$out = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $out);
```

can be replaced by another line that do another changes to print_r like this :

```
$out = explode("\n", $out, 2)[1];
```