# Is it possible to change the behavior of PHP's print_r function

Tags: php, windows

I've been coding in PHP for a long time (15+ years now), and I usually do so on a Windows OS, though most of the time it's for execution on Linux servers. Over the years I've run up against an annoyance that, while not important, has proved to be a bit irritating, and I've gotten to the point where I want to see if I can address it somehow. Here's the problem:

When coding, I often find it useful to output the contents of an array to a text file so that I can view it's contents. For example:

```
$fileArray = file('path/to/file');
$faString = print_r($fileArray, true);
$save = file_put_contents('fileArray.txt', $faString);
```

Now when I open the file fileArray.txt in Notepad, the contents of the file are all displayed on a single line, rather than the nice, pretty structure seen if the file were opened in Wordpad. This is because, regardless of OS, PHP's print_r function uses \n for newlines, rather than \r\n. I can certainly perform such replacement myself by simply adding just one line of code to make the necessary replacements, ans therein lies the problem. That one, single line of extra code translates back through my years into literally hundreds of extra steps that should not be necessary. I'm a lazy coder, and this has become unacceptable.

Currently, on my dev machine, I've got a different sort of work-around in place (shown below), but this has it's own set of problems, so I'd like to find a way to "coerce" PHP into putting in the "proper" newline characters without all that extra code. I doubt that this is likely to be possible, but I'll never find out if I never ask, so...

Anyway, my current work-around goes like this. I have, in my PHP include path, a file (print_w.php) which includes the following code:

```
<?php

  function print_w($in, $saveToString = false) {
    $out = print_r($in, true);
    $out = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $out);
    switch ($saveToString) {
      case true: return $out;
      default: echo $out;
    }
  }
?>
```

I also have auto_prepend_file set to this same file in php.ini, so that it automatically includes it every time PHP executes a script on my dev machine. I then use the function print_w instead of print_r while testing my scripts. This works well, so long as when I upload a script to a remote server I make sure that all references to the function print_w are removed or commented out. If I miss one, I (of course) get a fatal error, which can prove more frustrating than the original problem, but I make it a point to carefully proofread my code prior to uploading, so it's not often an issue.

So after all that rambling, my question is, Is there a way to change the behavior of print_r (or similar PHP functions) to use Windows newlines, rather than Linux newlines on a Windows machine?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: me too did :P nothing changes. That's why I deleted my last comment. I personally use things like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4282183/1437261  (I use Yii framework which has it inbuilt).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've thought about just digging into PHP's codebase and making the changes to the behavior there, but I'm not THAT kind of coder, so I could potentially break things. As to using Yii (or any other sort of framework), that's not always an option, as I'm a freelance developer, and not all clients are open to the idea of using "new tech", so that's not a universal option for me.

Comment: Why don't you try using var_export ? It will make it look like a nice looking json.

Comment: That's the same suggestion that @noc2spam had, which has the same problem of using Linux newlines for it's output. Thus, it didn't solve my problem. But thanks anyway. Please see my answer, below, for a solution that seems to work for me.

Comment: I've [added a a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663586/making-print-r-use-php-eol/35695427#35695427) to the linked dupe that doesn't require messing with apd or runkit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after further research, I've found a better work-around that suite my needs, and eliminates the need to call a custom function instead of print_r. This new work-around goes like this:

I still have to have an included file (I've kept the same name so as not to have to mess with php.ini), and php.ini still has the auto_prepend_file setting in place, but the code in print_w.php is changes a bit:

```
<?php

  rename_function('print_r', 'print_rw');

  function print_r($in, $saveToString = false) {
    $out = print_rw($in, true);
    $out = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $out);
    switch ($saveToString) {
      case true: return $out;
      default: echo $out;
    }
  }

?>
```

This effectively alters the behavior of the print_r function on my local machine, without my having to call custom functions, and having to make sure that all references to that custom function are neutralized. By using PHP's [rename_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) I was able to effectively rewrite how print_r behaves, making it possible to address my problem.

Comment: I didn't know such a function exists! Thanks for the rename_function thingy. +1.

Comment: The function is actually part of a PECL library called apd. It's a pain in the butt to install, but once there, it helps a lot.